# Como resolver o erro ( code: "storage/unauthorized" ) dentro do firebase storage

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

Estou aqui com um painel angular para dar manutenção. Tudo que preciso fazer é um upload de um arquivo em pdf para o servidor, e retornar o url de download deste mesmo arquivo. Porém estou esbarrando neste erro e não consigo sair do lugar. Já pesquisei em vários lugares, tentei diversas soluções e nenhuma resolveu o meu problema. Alguém poderia me dizer como eu posso resolver este erro?

O meu trecho de código é:

```
enviarNotaFiscal() {
console.log('upando a nota fiscal');
const name = this.notaFiscal.name;
const ref = this.afs.ref(`notasfiscais/nota.pdf`);
const task = ref.put(this.notaFiscal);
task.percentageChanges().subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
task.then(data => {
  data.ref.getDownloadURL().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
})
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

}

O erro que me retorna no console é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O mais interessante que este código é o mesmo que costumo utilizar em meus projetos, portanto acredito que o problema esteja na configuração do projeto do firebase ou algo assim, porém como não iniciei este projeto, não sei responder.

Qualquer ajuda será bem vinda.

Answer (score 0):

um erro bobo da minha parte. Os caminhos do storage nas regras de segurança e nas configurações do projeto estavam diferentes, fiz a correção e tudo ocorreu dentro do esperado.
Problema resolvido.